# Pass Query String Paramater in RouteTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm creating a Route in the Global.asax file like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("MyRoute", 
"myroute", "~/SomePage.aspx?parameter=123");
```

As you can see, I want to pass a query string parameter from the route definition.

In the code-behind page, I want to access the parameter but when I do this:

```
var TheParameter = Request.QueryString["parameter"];
```

The variable is null.

How do I pass a parameter from the Route table?

I want to do something like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("MyRoute123", 
"myroute123", "~/SomePage.aspx?parameter=123");
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("MyRoute456", 
"myroute456", "~/SomePage.aspx?parameter=456");
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("MyRoute789", 
"myroute789", "~/SomePage.aspx?parameter=789");
```

All routes processed by the same .aspx page and I need different URLs to be processed by the same page.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good fit to use [`RouteData.DataTokens`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.datatokens(v=vs.110).aspx). You would setup your route like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(
        routeName: "MyRoute123",
        routeUrl: "myroute123",
        physicalFile: "~/SomePage.aspx",
        checkPhysicalUrlAccess: false,
        defaults: null,
        constraints: null,
        dataTokens: new RouteValueDictionary { { "parameter", "123" } }
    );
```

Then retrieve the parameter like this:

```
object parameter;
if (Page.RouteData.DataTokens.TryGetValue("parameter", out parameter))
{
    // do something w/ parameter
}
```

Comment: Ok, didn't know about this; I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like it's the correct one but since then I've changed things around and I'm doing it differently. Upvoted and accepted anyway; thanks.